# Homotoping curves in 3/4-manifolds to lie on embedded tori?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

I am wondering if every simple closed curve $c$ in a 3-manifold $Y$ can be homotoped to lie on an embedded torus?  Maybe I need to assume that the 3-manifold is orientable?

[EDIT: As @JohnHughes points out - the answer is yes if we assume $Y$ is orientable, or more generally if $c$ is orientation preserving.  ]

Similarly, I am wondering if every simple closed curve $c$ in a 4-manifold $X$ can be homotoped to lie on an embedded torus?

Any sufficient conditions on $X$ are also appreciated if the answers to the above turn out to be no.

Answer (score 4):

If $Y$ is orientable and smooth and compact, I think it's true:

Take your curve $\gamma$; the tubular neighborhood theorem says that a neighborhood of $\gamma$ looks like a 2-disk-bundle over $\gamma$, and since these are classified by "clutching functions" in $\pi_0(O(2))$, there are only two possibilities. For the case where the clutching element is in $O(2)- SO(2)$, you've got a nonorientable bundle, and that makes $\gamma$ an orientation-reversing look in $Y$, which contradicts the "orientable" assumption. So...it's actually diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times D^2$. Now consider the image of $S^1 \times C$, where $C$ is the radius-one-half circle in $D^2$ under this diffeomorphism. That'll be a torus in $Y$. And picking a section of the resulting $S^1$ bundle over $\gamma$ gives a curve homotopic to $\gamma$ that lies on the surface of the torus.

@Camilo's answer seems to be addressing the harder question of whether it lies on an embedded torus that has some non-triviality property that I cannot quite discern.

Comment: Yes that sounds good to me - thank you.  I am going to leave things open as I am still curious about the 4-manifold case.

Comment: Pretty much the same argument holds in a smooth oriented 4-manifold, assuming again that $\gamma$ is smooth. Any tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$ is diffeomorphic to $D^3 \times S^1$ where $\gamma$ corresponds to $\mathcal{O} \times S^1$ and $\mathcal{O} \in D^3$ is the origin. Taking a smooth embedding $S^1 \hookrightarrow D^3$ passing through $\mathcal{O}$, and then crossing with $S^1$, produces the desired torus.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I should have seen/mentioned that.